# Establish a trigonometry-based $floor$ function

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have established the following function for calculating $floor$:

$$f(x)=x-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\arcsin(\sin(\pi(x-\frac{1}{2})))}{\pi}$$

It works correctly for all real values in the range $[2N+0,2N+1)$, for every integer $N$.

It works incorrectly for almost all real values in the range $[2N+1,2N+2)$, for every integer $N$.

I believe that I can work it out by changing the domain of $x$, though I can't quite figure out how...

Any ideas?

---

Please see a few examples below:

- $f(2.0)=2.0 = \lfloor 2.0 \rfloor$
- $f(2.1)=2.0 = \lfloor 2.1 \rfloor$
- $f(2.2)=2.0 = \lfloor 2.2 \rfloor$
- $f(2.3)=2.0 = \lfloor 2.3 \rfloor$
- $f(2.4)=2.0 = \lfloor 2.4 \rfloor$
- $f(2.5)=2.0 = \lfloor 2.5 \rfloor$
- $f(2.6)=2.0 = \lfloor 2.6 \rfloor$
- $f(2.7)=2.0 = \lfloor 2.7 \rfloor$
- $f(2.8)=2.0 = \lfloor 2.8 \rfloor$
- $f(2.9)=2.0 = \lfloor 2.9 \rfloor$
- $f(3.0)=2.0 \neq \lfloor 3.0 \rfloor$
- $f(3.1)=2.2 \neq \lfloor 3.1 \rfloor$
- $f(3.2)=2.4 \neq \lfloor 3.2 \rfloor$
- $f(3.3)=2.6 \neq \lfloor 3.3 \rfloor$
- $f(3.4)=2.8 \neq \lfloor 3.4 \rfloor$
- $f(3.5)=3.0 = \lfloor 3.5 \rfloor$
- $f(3.6)=3.2 \neq \lfloor 3.6 \rfloor$
- $f(3.7)=3.4 \neq \lfloor 3.7 \rfloor$
- $f(3.8)=3.6 \neq \lfloor 3.8 \rfloor$
- $f(3.9)=3.8 \neq \lfloor 3.9 \rfloor$
- $f(4.0)=4.0 = \lfloor 4.0 \rfloor$

Comment: Consider the well-known Fourier series:

$$\lfloor x \rfloor = x - \frac12 +\frac1{\pi} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin{2 \pi k x}}{k}$$

I'm not sure how you resolve the sum in terms of a single arcsine.

Comment: Thank you @Ron Gordon, but I would like to avoid using series (infinite series in particular).

Comment: Sure, but my point is, an expression for a floor is indeed an infinite series.  How do you resolve this in terms of a single arcsine?  I doubt this is possible in general.

Comment: @Ron Gordon: That's the purpose of this question. The proposed function appears to be working correctly **without any use of infinite series**, but not for all values.

Comment: What's the difference between "working... but not for all values" and "not working"?

Comment: @David, it works **incorrectly** for all real values in the range $[2N+1,2N+2)$, except for $2N+1.5$.

Comment: Plot the graph of $\arcsin(\sin(x))$, and you will see why you have the problem.  The slope is $1$ or $-1$ depending upon which range you are in: $[2\pi n,2\pi n+\pi]$, or $[2\pi n+\pi,2\pi n+2\pi]$.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to do this successfully without making some pretty major changes.

Reason: polynomials, sine and inverse sine are all continuous at all points of their domain.  So any sums, differences, products, quotients and compositions of these functions will also be continuous.  The sort of expression you are currently looking at, therefore, even if you make some minor adjustments, will never equal the floor function.

Comment: Not quotients though.

Comment: Yes, quotients too: the quotient of continuous functions is continuous *at every point of its domain* - this obviously precludes division by zero.

Comment: Right. So tangent should work (see my answer).

Comment: Unless I misread the question, the OP wants something defined for all real $x$.  So the tangent cannot work in the complete sense.

Comment: I see from his page that he is an engineer, so he is probably pretty open-minded.

Comment: lol ;-)$\hbox{}$

Comment: Your answer is simply not true. The function suggested in the answer given by $user72694$ is not continuous.

Comment: Definition: a function is said to be *continuous* if it is continuous at every point **of its domain**.  Think about it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with sine is that it is not monotone on its period.  I would therefore use tangent instead.  Try $x-\arctan(\tan(x))$.  This should be locally flat.  By rescaling the variables you should be able to get the floor.  Of course, there are points where this is undefined, but it works for almost all points :-)

Comment: Thanks, but simply replacing $\pi$ with $2\pi$ doesn't work (I've already tried that).

Comment: How about using $|\sin x|$ in place of $\sin x$?  This way you also get a function with period 1.

Comment: My purpose is to establish a $floor$ function without using $ceiling$, $round$, $abs$, etc.

Comment: Is square root OK?

Comment: Yes!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: $x-\arctan(\tan(x))$ just gives $0$ for every $-1.5  \leq x \leq +1.5$. For every $x > 1.5$, it gives $\pi$ and for every $x < -1.5$, it gives $-\pi$.

Comment: That's hard to believe.  If $x=1000000\pi$ then $\tan x=0$ and so $\arctan\tan x=0$ but $x\not=\pi$.

Comment: OK, sorry, need to divide the result by $\pi$.

Comment: That seems to do it then, modulo rescaling the variable by $\pi$ as well.

Comment: It's a partial answer in any case. Doesn't give me $floor$. And as I mentioned earlier, I am also trying to avoid use of $modulo$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize you want the moon and the stars, as well :-)

Comment: You don't need modulo, just multiply the variable by pi.

Comment: Sorry, but I am unable to "turn" your suggestion of $x−\arctan(\tan(x))$ into a $floor$ function.

Comment: What do you get for this expression?

Comment: For $0 \leq x \leq 1.5$, I get $0$. For $1.6 \leq x \leq 4.7$, I get $\pi$. For $4.8 \leq x \leq 7.8$, I get $2\pi$...

Comment: What do you get for $f(\pi x)$?

Comment: Do you mean $\pi x − \arctan(\tan(\pi x))$? Or do you mean $x − \arctan(\tan(\pi x))$?

Comment: The former formula.

Comment: I get $\pi\lceil x-\frac{1}{2} \rceil$.

Comment: Well, it refutes the answer given by @David to begin with.

Comment: And this makes it almost perfect: $x-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\arctan(\tan(\pi(x-\frac{1}{2})))}{pi}$, with the exception of integer numbers, which get their $floor$ values minus $1$.

Comment: I suggest you add 1 to attain perfection.

Comment: Add $1$ to what?

Comment: I thought you said your answer was off by 1 ?

Comment: No, I said integer numbers were off by $1$.

Comment: It's equivalent to $\lceil x-1 \rceil$. How do you convert that to $\lfloor x \rfloor$?

Comment: @barakmanos: $\lceil x \rceil = - \lfloor -x \rfloor$.

Comment: @Willie Wong: Thanks, but unfortunately I have $\lceil x-1 \rceil$ at hand.

Comment: @barak: yes, and $\lceil x - 1\rceil = \lceil x \rceil - 1$. The rest I certainly hope you can do by yourself.

Comment: @Willie Wong: Not really. $x+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\arctan(\tan(\pi(-x-\frac{1}{2})))}{\pi} = \lceil x \rceil$ for all values except negative integers. So I cannot use $-\lfloor -x \rfloor$.

Comment: @barak: all I can say is, do not use the $\lceil \cdot\rceil$ notation when you do not actually mean the ceiling function.

Comment: @Willie Wong: I do mean the ceiling function.